# How to let url with anchor tags show a hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

How can I show an hidden div when using anchors that are linked with their linked a tag that is in the hidden div. If you know what I mean..

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2sjdeucf/

I mean when visiting the url site.com/#1 Then I want the div shown, so the same like when you press on the button named 1.

Html

```
    <a href="#1">1</a>
<a href="#2">2</a>
<a href="#3">3</a>
<br><br><br>
<div id="clicks"> 
 <a class="click" id="showInfo" data-target=".1"><button>1</button></a>
 <a class="click" id="showDataInput" data-target=".2"><button>2</button></a>
 <a class="click" id="showHistory" data-target=".3"><button>3</button></a>
</div>
    <div class="1 target" style="display: none;"><a name="1">1</a></div>
    <div class="2 target" style="display: none;"><a name="1">2</a></div>
    <div class="3 target" style="display: none;"><a name="1">3</a></div>
<div id="text">"I WANT THIS DIV GONE EVERYTIME I LET DIV 1, 2 OR 3 SHOW BY CLICKING THE BUTTONS. BUT SHOW UP AGAIN WHEN 1, 2 OR 3 IS NOT SHOWING/SELECTED"</div>
```

Javascript

```
    var $targets = $('.target');
$('#clicks .click').click(function () {
    var $target = $($(this).data('target')).toggle();
    $targets.not($target).hide();
    $('#text').css('display', $('div.target:visible').length ? 'none':'')
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Note that the use of integers as class name should be avoided according to w3c and may outcome to buggy results (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html)

Comment: In the sample code you stated, neither $targets nor $target is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need get initial hash and subscribe for hash changes via onhashchange, so your code becomes (I slightly modified your code, final version is, tested locally in Chrome):

```
  function doToggle(num) {
      var target = $('div.target' + num);
      target.toggle();
      $('.target').not(target).hide();
      $('#text').css('display', $('div.target:visible').length ? 'none' : '')
  }
  $('#clicks .click').click(function () {
      var num = $(this).data('target');
      doToggle(num);
  });
  function handleHash() {
      doToggle("." + location.hash.substring(1));
  }
  window.onhashchange = handleHash;
  $(handleHash);
```

Comment: Possibly a small bug, depending on requirements: Click the "1" link, then the "2" button, then the "2" link hides the "2" div. (http://jsfiddle.net/73z48jr2/39/)

Comment: may be, didn't change this part, left it as is - author knows better ). Actually it's bad practice to mix anchor management and direct content management. Better to change buttons to send to appropriate hash always and have function which does all the job for given hash state. I have wrote library for this, learned hashes perfect.

Comment: Yes i've accidently used another fiddle. This was the correct one: http://jsfiddle.net/2sjdeucf/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [:target](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/t/target/) pseudoclass and hash based links ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3))

```
div {
  display: none;
}
div:target {
  display: block;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sunstory/1mvwb83j/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.hash` to detect the values after the hash.

exp:

```
    var val=window.location.hash.substring(1);//substring to remove the #
    if(val.length!==0){
        $(".target").hide();
        $("."+val).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand well but I tried to stick to your instruction within your .text div, so this code shoud do the trick :

```
function showHideDiv() {
    $('.target').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':visible')){
            $('#text').hide();
        }
    });
}
$(document).on('load', showHideDiv);
$('.click').on('click', showHideDiv);

$('#clicks .click').click(function () {
    $('div.target' + $(this).data('target')).toggle();
    $('#text').css('display', $('div.target:visible').length ? 'none':'')
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73z48jr2/38/)

Comment: Yes i've also use another fiddle accidently.. This was the correct one. http://jsfiddle.net/2sjdeucf/. Thank you for your help!